# How to create an object who have alias for many others object's functions

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, multiple-inheritance

I have a situation here.
Let's show an example:

```
function ScrewDriver(){
    var data = ...;
    this.driving = function(){
        //Some Stuff Here
    }
}

function Hammer(){
    var data = ...;
    this.stomp = function(){
        //Some Stuff Here
    }
}

function MultiTools(){
    this.screwDriver = new ScrewDriver();
    this.hammer = new Hammer();
}
```

Here is the base of our example.
Now I would like redirect the tools functions from the multiTools but dynamicaly.
Let's explain myself:

```
function Work(){
    this.tools = new MultiTools();
    this.tools.screw(); // I want to user directly the function of the proper object
    this.tools.hammer.stomp(); // Not like this;
}
```

I was thinking of something like that:

```
function MultiTools(){
    this.screwDriver = new ScrewDriver();
    this.hammer = new Hammer();
    for(var prop in this.screwDriver){
        this[prop] = this.screwDriver[prop];
    }
    //Same for each object
}
```

But it's not working like I want because if I acces to the child object data in the child object function I'll get an error.
When im calling this.tools.screw(); I want in reality this.tools.screwDriver.screw();
In finally I just want a redirection.

Someone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.bind()`:

```
   this[prop] = this.screwDriver[prop].bind(this.screwDriver);
```

That ensures that when the functions are called, they'll have the correct value of `this`.

You could write a general function for your MultiTools object:

```
function MultiTools() {
  var multitool = this;
  function promoteMethods(subobj) {
    for (var prop in subobj)
      if (typeof subobj[prop] == 'function')
        multitool[prop] = subobj[prop].bind(subobj);
      else
        multitool[prop] = subobj[prop];
  }

  promoteMethods(this.hammer = new Hammer());
  promoteMethods(this.screwDriver = new ScrewDriver());
  // ...
}
```